# apache/nifi docker e postgresql Driver

Tags: postgresql, docker

Fiz o pull do apache/nifi no docker hub. Inicio o container, mas não consigo configurar a conexão com o postgres, Fica disparando uma exceção de que não consegue carregar o Database Driver.

Copiei o arquivo .jar do driver do postgresql pra dentro do container, pus em vários diretórios e mesmo assim não consigo acertar.

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Comment: Como e para onde você copia o driver para o container? Como está a configuração do _controller service_? Pode incluir a _stack trace_ do erro?

Comment: Bruno, eu subi o container com 'docker run --name nifi -p 9090:9090 -d -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT='9090' --network benchdocker_default --link inttegra apache/nifi:latest' depois copio o postgresql-42.2.2.jar via docker cp. Acesso o bash do container e listo os arquivos e vejo que ele está lá na raiz. Nas configurações do NiFi o caminho do arquivo está file:///postgresql-42.2.2.jar

Comment: Quanto ao caminho do arquivo, aqui não uso este `file://`, a _stack trace_ ao tentar habilitar o _service_ deve está falando que não achou o arquivo, que ele não é válido, etc. Como exemplo, aqui uso assim: `/opt/nifi/nifi-1.6.0/custom-libs/postgresql-42.2.2.jar`. Quando incluir a _stack trace_ posso te falar com certeza, pode ser permissão do usuário também.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, era algum erro de digitação talvez, hoje já funcionou.